# can't run a java code with owlapi

Tags: owl-api

i'm new to owlapi and i'm trying to write a sample java code on debian to load an ontology that i already built using protégé. I'm using "owlapi-osgidistribution-4.0.2.jar", but i always get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.vocab.OWLFacet.<init>(OWLFacet.java:87)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.vocab.OWLFacet.<clinit>(OWLFacet.java:60)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.vocab.OWL2Datatype$Category.<clinit>(OWL2Datatype.java:328)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.vocab.OWL2Datatype.<clinit>(OWL2Datatype.java:74)
at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.InternalsNoCache.<clinit>(InternalsNoCache.java:59)
at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLDataFactoryImpl.<init>(OWLDataFactoryImpl.java:128)
at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLDataFactoryImpl.<clinit>(OWLDataFactoryImpl.java:74)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.getOWLDataFactory(OWLManager.java:152)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager(OWLManager.java:113)
at LoadingOntologies.main(LoadingOntologies.java:22) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 10 more
```

i tried to use maven for dependency but in vain.
can anyone tell me how to solve this problem please, thanks.

Comment: " tried to use maven for dependency but in vain" what does that mean? Were you unable to use maven at all or did the dependencies get resolved? Also do you have the Google Guava jar in your project setup?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the guava jars. For OWLAPI 4.0.2, you also need all other jars included in the maven dependencies. If you could not use Maven to build your code, you'll need to make sure all the dependencies are added manually.

Can you describe what you have tried with Maven, and what errors you got?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to get all the dependencies is via Maven. Locating JARs manually takes too much time.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```